# When writing tests in Truffle, is it possible to force specific wallet addresses to be used?

Tags: solidity, truffle, testrpc, testing

I have Solidity code that, given the input of the sender's wallet address, deterministically produces a resulting output.

My goal is to write a unit test for this functionality.  Is there a way I can override the msg.sender value?

I'm using Truffle 4.0.4 alongside testrpc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve that would be to run testrpc always using the same mnemonic which will always generate the same accounts.

You can do that by doing `testrpc -m "word1 word2 word3 word..."`

Comment: Ah, of course!  I'll do that.  Thanks for the recommendation.